# Solr Blob Store API - Blob Too Big

Tags: curl, solr

I am trying to use the Blob Store API to post a jar into the .system collection so that I can load a custom solr plugin onto all of my nodes. Trying to post the jar using:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --data-binary @myjar.jar http://localhost:9002/solr/.system/blob/myjar
```

But my fat jar is 81 mb and it is overflowing the SimplePostTool's buffer. Is there a way to increase this? I'm trying to load a custom solr plugin into Solr 6 Cloud.

The error:

```
  "trace":"java.nio.BufferOverflowException\n\tat org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool.inputStreamToByteArray(SimplePostTool.java:644)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.BlobHandler.handleRequestBody(BlobHandler.java:102)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2036)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:657)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n",
```

Answer (score 2):

The default size of an object in the blob store is 5MB. You can increase the maximum size by using the `-Dblob.max.size.mb=nnn` config value. Be mindful that blobs are kept on the heap, and that you may need to use the `runtimeLib=true` when creating the request handler. (This information, and more, can be found in the following links.)

The wiki page, including the comments at the bottom, is very informative.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Blob+Store+API

The SOLR jira ticket to create the blob store feature has discussion related to the default size:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6787